# When i am trying to deploy this code on snowflake i am getting this error use schema. I have tried using fully qualified name as well use schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, liquibase

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current schema. Call 'USE SCHEMA', or use a qualified name. [Failed SQL: (90106) CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP_NTZ, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]

Comment: Hi Sonal, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please formulate a question with some more details instead of just pasting your error and hoping for a magical answer. Keep in mind that this makes it easier for others to help you and future visitors with the same question can find and understand your problem easier. Thanks in advance, and welcome once again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this statement before creating the table

Use Database DB_Name;
Use Schema Schema_Name;

The DB_Name and Schema_Name is required before you create a table.
The values for these are taken from your account.

Or You can use this syntax

Create Table Db_Name.Schema_Name.Table_Name ( column names --- );

Comment: I have tried using both approaches but still the same error is coming. I am using Liquibase in windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the session/connection, is it from Snowflake UI or from any application?

Are you using the Snowflake JDBC connector?

**Did you provide schema privileges before execution?**

Grant schema permissions for the SQL statements: USAGE, CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SEQUENCE, and CREATE VIEW.

1. Please refer to this link for a connection from liquidbase to Snowflake

https://docs.liquibase.com/install/tutorials/snowflake.html

Other troubleshooting steps:

2. If it's from Snowflake UI, could you check the context what it's set to, which database, schema, table etc?
3. If its from the application, could you check what and all properties are being used to create the connection, and which default schema its using?

Can you upload the screenshot of the session (properties) and UI context (top right corner) if the issue still persists?

Thanks,
Sujan

Comment: The role which i am using is accountadmin so i dont think so we need to grant any access or usage to roles. #### Enter the Target database 'url' information  ####
liquibase.command.url=jdbc:snowflake://za55893.ap-south-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=PRANIT&warehouse=compute_wh&db=DEMO&schema=TEST; This we have passed in properties files

Comment: Hello Sonal,

I see user sonal1 is able to create the table 'CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK" successfully and later its gets error because the table already exists. You need to use "create or replace table syntax".    I hope the schema privileges resolved now as user sonal is able to create the table under TEST schema.